# Tether from PC to android via USB

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, internet, reverse-tether

Is there a way to tether a PC's ethernet or WiFi connection to a Samsung Galaxy Fame using Jelly Bean 4.1?

What I would like to do is to be able to access the internet on the phone using the PC's internet connection, via USB or wifi. My PC runs Ubuntu and Windows (Dual Boot) so either of these operating systems will work.

Comment: Have you checked the other [questions tagged reverse-tether](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether)? If so: what makes your situation so special that none of those matches? What have you already tried?

Comment: well that's the answer. Thanks to @GAThrawn for the tag - I didn't know it was called reverse tether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse tether your pc to your phone.